# problem with R grep() function in Rstudio 1.2.1335 for windows 10 running R 3.6.0

Tags: r, regex

this is my first time running Rstudio on windows. I'm having the weirdest problem with the R grep() function, which doesn't return the indices of the matches but rather return 1 when pattern found and integer(0) otherwise, much like grepl(). see the below example copied from my Rstudio console (sorry if separate lines are merged).

can anyone help with fixing this? I do need the index of the match for further data manipulation. Thanks so much!

```
> grep('abc', '1abc234abc')
[1] 1
> grep('abc', '55551abc234abc')
[1] 1
> grepl('abc', '55551abc234abc')
[1] TRUE
> grep('abc', '55551ab234ab')
integer(0)
> grepl('abc', '55551ab234ab')
[1] FALSE

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[9] base     

other attached packages:
[1] seqinr_3.4-5        Biostrings_2.52.0   XVector_0.24.0      IRanges_2.18.1     
[5] S4Vectors_0.22.0    BiocGenerics_0.30.0 xlsx_0.6.1          rJava_0.9-11       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] xlsxjars_0.6.1     MASS_7.3-51.4      zlibbioc_1.30.0    tools_3.6.0       
[5] ade4_1.7-13        compiler_3.6.0     BiocManager_1.30.4
```

Comment: Try passing a vector as the second argument and it will return vector indices that match. Maybe you're looking for `regexpr`,and `regmatches`

Comment: If you're talking *"index of the match"* **within the string**, then I suspect you are referring to position within each string (typically in R, "index" from `grep` refers to index of a string within a vector of strings, not a substring within a string). I agree with BrianDavis that `regexpr` (or `gregexpr`, actually) will give you what you need. See `gregexpr('abc', '1abc234abc')`, return substrings 2 (3 chars long) and 8 (3 chars long), if you read the values and attributes.

Comment: Because this question has nothing to do with RStudio (IDE) or the Windows OS or any Windows-isms of R, I've removed the two tags. And added [tag:regex], which I suspect to be key to your solution. If I'm wrong, my apologies, just rollback [my edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57366499/revisions) (or re-add the tags).

Answer (score 0):

@Brian Davis @r2evans thank you so much for your tips. I did mean the position of the substring. I will definitely try regexpr and gregexpr. And in all my life using R/Rstudio on MacOS or Linux, grep()has been returning me the position in the string where the searched pattern is matched. That’s why I thought the weird behavior of grep() I’m seeing now might have to do with the windows OS. Thank you @r2evans for fixing the format of my question. When I return to work next week, I’ll post updates.